# Get nodes adjacent to child node in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin

I'm fairly new to Gremlin and I'm trying to query a graph starting at my vertex Customer, which is related to various nodes amongst which is the Account node. And so, I want to retrieve all nodes related to the Customer node + all nodes related to the Account node connected to it.

As you can see in the image, my Customer node is related to the account node via the has_account edge. I would like to get all the nodes adjacent to that account node.

[Customer node](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CP9r.png)

As I said, I'm fairly new to neptune so what I've tried aside from the most basic visualizations is:

```
g.V('id').outE().inV().outE().inV().path()
```

And that gives me the nodes adjacent to the Account node but ommits the other adjacent nodes to the Customer node. I've also tried some other groupings and mappings but I can't seem to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query you wrote above, you are starting out a vertex `id` and then traversing to all of its connections (the first `outE().inV()`, and then the connections of the connections (the second `outE().inV()`).  If a connection does not have any connections, then it will be filtered out.

If you would like to return both the 1st and optionally 2nd connections, then I would look at using the [optional()](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#optional-step) step for the 2nd+ level connections that may or may not exist like this:

```
g.V('id').outE().inV().optional(outE().inV()).path()
```

Comment: Makes total sense! I will try it out and update this comment later.

Comment: Update, it works! Huge thank you.